# How to modify text in heading attr in angular bootstrap accordion

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am using accordion from angular bootstrap and I encountered a problem. I have the following code for the accordion:

```
<accordion close-others="true">
    <accordion-group heading="Living Room  Status: Complete">
        //some content
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="Bed Room  Status: Complete">
        //some content
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

The problem here is the header text is always left-aligned. I want the word "**Status:Complete**" to be right aligned but how can I do that?

[image]

**Additional Info**: I'm using this file from angular bootstrap >> **ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js**

Comment: Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/6zev5e4w/

Comment: huwwow. I didnt know heading attr could be a tag. it worked perfectly. Put your answer below so I could mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution might help you

```
<accordion close-others="true">
    <accordion-group heading="Living Room  Status: Complete">
       <accordion-heading>
        <p class="clearfix" style="margin-bottom: 0;"><span  style="float: left;">Living Room</span> <span style="float: right;">Status: Complete</span></p>
       </accordion-heading>
  This content is straight in the template.
</accordion-group>
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="Bed Room  Status: Complete">
     <accordion-heading>
        <p class="clearfix" style="margin-bottom: 0;"><span  style="float: left;">Bed Room</span> <span style="float: right;">Status: Complete</span></p>
       </accordion-heading>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Comment: @themyth92 already gave an answer in comments and his answer is almost the same as yours. And yeah, it worked.

Comment: yep i seen jsfiddle BUT after post my answer. Thanks